# Change background-color with input value

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form in which user can set a hexa color. 
I want to put a block next to the input "color" and that this block change background color according to the input value. I want to make this dynamically, a bit like a color picker. I think we can do this with js but I don't know how. Also I do this with rails if it can help.

I already have this

```
<div class="field color">
    <label for="activite_color">Color</label>
    <input type="text" value="BF4139" name="activite[color]" id="activite_color" />
    <span class="col-lg-1" style="background:#BF4139;"></span>
</div>
```

And the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rt7h6wd3/)

Comment: Do you need to build your own from scratch or can you use one of the many plugins for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `maxlength="6"` to `textbox`:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="BF4139" name="activite[color]" id="activite_color" maxlength="6" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#activite_color').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.col-lg-1').css('background', '#' + $(this).val());
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rt7h6wd3/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've got on input

```
$('#activite_color').on('input', function() {
    $('.col-lg-1').css('background', '#' + $(this).val());
});
```

any of the answers so far will work though

https://jsfiddle.net/rt7h6wd3/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#activite_color').change(function () {
        $('.col-lg-1').css('background', '#' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Check the update on your jsfidder which i have made.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

Html:
`<input type="text">`

```
Script
$("input").blur(function(){
   var col = "#" + $("input").val();
   $("body").css("background-color", col);
});
```

remember color code is 6 digit. so enter 6 digit in text box.